# Why my pure CSS parallax does not work?

Tags: css

I wanna control the scroll speed of different elements with pure CSS (no javascript) as parallax.

So, I watched this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9zLJ0I8Djk .

Now, look my code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                perspective: 1px;
                height: 1000px;
            }
            .group {
                -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
            }
            .back {
                transform: translateZ(-1px);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="group">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" class="back">
            <p class="front">Avril</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why for me, it doesn't work ? What do I forgot to do ?

Comment: Just watching the last minute of this video shows that you miss 90% of the CSS of this example. Check the code here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9zLJ0I8Djk

Comment: No, just in the middle of the video he already succeded to do this. So, say me exactly what I forgot to do in my code because i am blocked on it since the beggining of the day.

Comment: Right now, your code can't do a parallax effect. Why? You need 2 elements to see something is moving the parallax way (parallax is an effect from on object relative to another). Moreover, right now your code basically says : the body height should be 1000px, and the .back element should be -1px on Z axis. All of this means: you won't and can't see any effect at this point. This could never render a parallax effect.

Comment: It is especially a difficult job for me. Say me just the CSS property that i have to add to my code to make it working.

Comment: There is the two elements that you said: the back class is translateZ(-1px) and the front class is translateZ(0). So I don't understand at this moment.

Comment: -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1);?

Comment: Proxytype : it does not work

Comment: Sorry, I missed the title at the bottom...

Comment: Well I made a live demo, depending on your window height, the effect is actually working : https://jsfiddle.net/ypcqwszc/1/

Comment: Why yours is working but not mine ?

Comment: As I said, it works depending the window height. Try to resize your window so the example run in a 300px height window. You'll see the effect. Going further in the video you mentioned will make the effect more visible.